# Pandas Time Diffrerence into Minutes,

Tags: python, pandas

After computing the time diffrence in Pandas DataFrame, I am not able to get the Time Difference in Number of Minutes,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2019] * 5,'month': [8] * 5,'day': [16] * 5,'hour': [12, 12, 12, 12, 13],
                   'minute': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2019] * 5,'month': [7] * 5,'day': [22] * 5,'hour': [11, 12, 12, 13, 14],
                   'minute': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df), columns=['Time_Stamp'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df_2), columns=['Time_Stamp_2'])
df['Time_Stamp_2']=df_2['Time_Stamp_2']
df['TimeDiff'] =  df.Time_Stamp - df.Time_Stamp_2
df
```

Tried `df['TimeDiff'].dt.seconds/60` but, that ignored the Days difference.

Comment: **total_seconds**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run: `(df.Time_Stamp - df.Time_Stamp_2) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [**`total_seconds()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html)

```
df['TimeDiff'] = (df.Time_Stamp - df.Time_Stamp_2).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
```

The `TimdeDiff` column:

```
0    36060.0
1    36000.0
2    36000.0
3    35940.0
4    35940.0
Name: TimeDiff, dtype: float64
```

Comment: any reason to use `.div` instead of just normal `/`

Comment: It helps in chaining. (if you have more functions / transformation down the road.) @Poojan